# Debugging Azure Worker Role locally throws build error: Access to the path 'diagnostics.wadcfgx' is denied

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-emulator

I have a fully functional cloud service Worker Role that I have been using and debugging for a couple weeks now.  I recently moved the solution into source control.  I can build the solution still, but when I try to run it locally on the emulator to debug I get the error

*Access to the path 'diagnostics.wadcfgx' is denied.*

I have everything checked out to edit so I know it isn't a read only issue on the file.  I can't figure out why this is happening or how to fix it.

My old version still runs locally on the emulator just fine.  I have modified the projects in the solution and updated naming conventions of the roles and projects.  My guess is that something was missed or a connection between the role project and the service project was lost... however I cannot figure out what it is.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem ended up being that one of the diagnostics.wadcfgx files was still marked as read only in the file system.  The best solution was to remove the entire ECF folder from source control.  When the project ran it recreated the directory and files needed.